# SQL trigger for add some data

Tags: mysql, triggers

Thank you for your help.

I have 3 tables on MySQL. One Table for my users and second is for my user features, the third one is for roles. First of all, I need to add registration on a measures table when the user is inserted. I mean if I add a new user to tbl_users the trigger will grab the user id and write on the tbl_measures that's it. I need just this.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_measures (user_id) VALUES (tbl_users.id)
```

this my triggers it is working partly. when I add a new user trigger add a new line to tbl_measures without id.

[image: tables shema]

Comment: Your question mentions MySQL, but you tagged in SQL Server and Postgres. These are 3 different products. I removed the database tags, please add only the relevant one.

Answer (score 1):

When you refer `NEW.id` in your `insert` `trigger`, there are two main cases. In the first case you get the proper `id` value. This is what you expect. In the second case it's `null`. This is what happens.

Essential is whether the `trigger` runs `before` or `after` the `insert`. `Before` the `insert` the `id` does not exist, because the record was not created yet. `After` the `insert` the `id` exists. Long story short code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER PROOFOFCONCEPT
AFTER INSERT
ON EACH ROW
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO tbl_measures(user_id)
    VALUES (NEW.id);

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_members_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `tbl_users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl_measures(user_id)
        VALUES(new.id);
END
```